# Test the speed of a local web page

Tags: javascript, extjs, localhost

I would like to test my web site, which url is localhost:8080/XXXXXXXX. Is there a way to test something that is local ?
It is developed in ExtJS, and I would like to run a test because it seems that one page is very very long to get for the client.

Comment: If it's local, it should be instant anyway, because you get no network lag. It's not representative of how your final users will load the page through the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open google chrome
2. Press F12
3. Go to "lighthouse" tab
4. Click on "generate report"

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question is vague to me but seems like you can use this as a guide.
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/speed/get-started